# What do I need to do, to be placed in the bus location of Apple Maps?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to be sure my app is placed in the bus section of Apple Maps... what code do I need to write to do this?

I couldn't find any documentation on Apple's website for how to be placed on the list... How does apple know what location my Bus App can handle?

I did the following, but is this enough? How does apple know what location on the map to present my bus app?

> [image]
>   [image: Xcode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html